# How to format date in 09-Nov-2014 format with DateFormatter in iOS & Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker, dateformatter

I'm trying to format date in date picker. I can't seem to find the format to display date in **09-Nov-2014** format. It always displays in Nov 09, 2014 format. I did a lot of search but can't figure out which one is the correct format to input. Can anyone help me out? Tx in advance.

```
@objc func datePickerValueChanged(sender:UIDatePicker) {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.medium
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.none
    dateOfBirthTextField.text = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)
}
```

Comment: Consider that  (ignoring the styles) `MM` prints `11` rather than `Nov` and that the `locale` is crucial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't set the styles. Just set the format.

You use either `dateFormat` or you use `dateStyle` and `timeStyle`.

Please note it's best to avoid using `dateFormat` for dates you wish to show to the user since your hardcoded format won't be standard for most users.

Also be aware that `MM` show the month number. If you want the abbreviated month name, use `MMM`.

Comment: Tx for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use `dateStyle` & `timeStyle` here you need a specific date format, your code should look like,

```
@objc func datePickerValueChanged(sender:UIDatePicker) {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
    dateOfBirthTextField.text = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry @rmaddy, I missed to observe your answer, yes I agree it looks same, I can remove the answer